# how to load image from server (url) to uitableview in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I need to load image from server(url) to `UITableView`. So i tired below code, but no use.

```
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
img.frame=fr;
img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:countimg]]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:img];
```

Here countimg is NSMutableArray. countimg contains url of all images to load. But its not working, because its not a string variable. I don't know how to change `NSMutuableArray` to String.

Anyone help me.

Comment: You have to pass it a valid URL string, not just NSMutableArray.
I think response is in JSON/XML. First parse response, get proper URL string to Image then pass it to NSURL URLWithString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get string urls from countimg array like this,

```
[countimg objectAtIndex:index];
```

Where index is an integer of range between >=0 && < `[countimg count]`

Now if you're using countimg array in `UITableView` delegate then, you've replace index variable with `indexPath.row`.

So for now your code would look like this,

```
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
img.frame=fr;
img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[countimg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]; //note this
[cell.contentView addSubview:img];
```

Update:
As @DavidAtkinson, suggestion, you should not use `dataWithContentsOfURL` method to load a `NSURL` to download a image. As its perform in main thread and will stuck the UI until download would not completes. Its better to load image in background.

Also, there's some asynchronous `UIImageView`'s available, one which I am using is [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Comment: @ David Atkinson Ya i too know this. But i dont know how to do it by asynchronous way. Can you guide me?

Comment: The above code is not working now. I don't know why it is happening like this. Can you help me.

Comment: @ Hemang EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x8) if comment code of loading image, it works fine.So how to load image.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SDWebImage` to load your image from server. here using this library you can put placeholder image in tableview cell's image view till the  image loaded. You can even cache your image by just doing a single line code 
`[UIImageView setImageWithUrl:[pass your URL here] placeholderImage:[pass name of placeholder image] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached]`

Comment: How to use SDWebimage. Can you guide me.

Comment: please first download code from github and then just copy sdwebimages file to your project. then import uiimageview+ webcache.h file to your class. and [imgView setimagewithurl: placeholderimage: options:] call this method

Comment: ok what happened ? which error comes? can u explain in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load your images from URL into a tableview,the SDWebImage code from Github does not specify how to do that.You have to create an object at index,then load the object for key name from the file you are parsing from.This will require you to change the SDWebImage code so that instead of parsing directly from a specific url,its parsing from 
an object key name that contains an image url from your json or xml file.

Here is a sample code for loading an image from an object key in a json:

```
     NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dictionaryObject valueForKey:@"yourfile"]];
     NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImageView *imgViewThumb=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imgView.frame];

        [imgViewThumb setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

        [cell addSubview:imgViewThumb];
```